# Formatting of entries such as "volume" "year" etc for References using BibTex

Tags: bibtex, citing, thesis

I hope this is not a duplicate, I've tried looking for related threads but didn't find any that answer my question.

I'm currently writing my thesis using Texifier (MacOS) and I do all my references using the BibTex format. My references all look like this:

[image]

Which corresponds to the BibTex entry in my "biliography.bib" file:

```
@article{BaumslagTaylor,
    author = {Gilbert Baumslag and Tekla Taylor},
    journal = {Mathematische Annalen},
    keywords = {group theory},
    pages = {315-319},
    title = {The Centre of Groups with One Defining Relator.},
    volume = {175},
    year = {1968},
}
```

I am now wondering if this is a comprehensible/accepted format for references or If one should format this to a form where the reference explicitly says **volume** 175, **pages** 315-319 etc. There are no requirements with respect to a citation format from my university. It's more a matter of design and readability I'm concerned with.

If so, how can I format the references accordingly?

Thanks for any help!

Edit: I'm using \bibliographystyle{alpha}

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: My apologies, I'm using: \bibliographystyle{alpha}

Comment: The `alpha` bibliography style has been around pretty much unchanged for  four decades or even longer. Millions, if not tens of millions, of published pieces have employed the `alpha` bib style along with BibTeX to generate citation call-outs and formatted bibliographic entries. Thus, your question whether the `alpha` bib style is "a comprehensible/accepted format for references" may easily be answered in the affirmative.

Comment: That's great to hear, then I do not need to worry. I was just concerned because all the DOI's looked even worse in the citations up to a point where I removed them entirely from every reference. I thought maybe everyone else maybe formats his references.

Comment: You may want to give up on employing the `ulem` package, though. Or, at the very least, do switch to loading `ulem` with the option `normalem`.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. May I ask what the consequences of ulem with respect to the bibliography are? Respectively the effect of normalem ?

Comment: Uh wow, I just did as you suggested. Everything looks so so much better. Thank you so much!

Comment: In fine typography, using underlining to emphasize something is considered to be almost vulgar. Do learn to use *italics* for emphasis.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, thank you vm!